# Combine two AJAX without jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

This is what I have and it works about 80% of the time but every once in a while it will crash. Can any combine these better? or at least check that both have returned a valid result before displaying. I tried setting as two separate functions and running them in tandem and that didn't work either for some reason. I would like to avoid jQuery if possible. Thanks

```
function doit(str){
        var color = document.getElementById('button').value;
    if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("Div1").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("Div2").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajaxRequesttwo = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        ajaxRequesttwo = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("Div1").innerHTML = ajaxRequesttwo.responseText;
                document.getElementById("Div2").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajaxRequesttwo.open("GET","ajax/page1.php?r="+str+"&c="+color,true);
    ajaxRequest.open("GET","ajax/page2.php?q="+str,true);
    ajaxRequesttwo.send();
    ajaxRequest.send();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to execute two AJAX requests, and set the output to the two divs after both are complete.

**Option 1**: Only let the latest AJAX request handler (can be either request) do the output display.

```
function doitnow(str) {
    // DOM elements / values
    var div1 = document.getElementById("Div1");
    var div2 = document.getElementById("Div2");
    var color = document.getElementById('button').value;

    // reset results
    if (str == "") {
        div1.innerHTML = "";
        div2.innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }

    // Prepare AJAX requests & handlers
    var ajaxRequest1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var ajaxRequest2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var result1, result2; // to store results of requests

    ajaxRequest1.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxRequest1.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest1.status == 200) {
            result1 = ajaxRequest1.responseText;
            attemptDisplay();
        }
    };
    ajaxRequest2.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxRequest2.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest2.status == 200) {
            result2 = ajaxRequest2.responseText;
            attemptDisplay();
        }
    };
    function attemptDisplay() {
        // display only if both results are set
        if (typeof result1 !== 'undefined' && typeof result2 !== 'undefined') {
            div1.innerHTML = result1;
            div2.innerHTML = result2;
        }
    }

    // Fire AJAX
    ajaxRequest2.open("GET","ajax/page1.php?r="+str+"&c="+color,true);
    ajaxRequest1.open("GET","ajax/page2.php?q="+str,true);
    ajaxRequest2.send();
    ajaxRequest1.send();
} //doitnow()
```

This should work. I didn't do the disgusting `ActiveXObject` thing because really, developers really shouldn't have to do this type of cross-browser "polyfilling" in the meat of the application. Use a proper XHR polyfill and henceforth, you may pretend that the legacy MS IE's AJAX construct doesn't exist. I recommend: https://github.com/Financial-Times/polyfill-service/blob/master/polyfills/XMLHttpRequest/polyfill.js

**Option 2**: ES-6 Promises

I know you're not keen on jQuery (and probably other libraries), but if you don't mind polyfilling your environment with ES-6 Promises, that can be an elegant solution as well, particularly through the use of `Promise.all`. It's essentially the same idea as Option 1, but abstracted away by the cleaner promises interface.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked well. I edited the two ) out of }); since they were probably left-overs. The rest of what you are saying is way above my head..hopefully someone else understands it..

Comment: Which part did you not understand? All I'm saying is you shouldn't have to do: ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") - use a polyfill instead. And for option 2 promises, ignore if you aren't familiar.

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking the ready state of one of the two Ajax requests. What happens if the other isn't ready when the first one is? Perhaps try adding another handler separately. Also, unless you're supporting very old versions of IE (I think below 8 even) you don't need to create an ActiveXObject as a fallback.

```
ajaxRequesttwo.onreadystatechange = function(){...}
```

Comment: believe it or not our browers at work are ie7.. they are beyond slow to update

Comment: Even for the developers!? Time for a new job. Lol